# USB to USBC only for one device?

Tags: cable

Can products be made such that only the cable they provide will charge it?

I have a baby sound machine, which has a USB to USBC cable that the company provides. It's too short and I've tried other cables (USBC to USBC and USB to USBC), but they don't work? The company (Noddiee) has said only their cable will charge it.

It seems like just a standard USB to USBC cable so I don't understand how that's possible?!

Comment: It would help to know what is this baby sound machine.

Answer (score 0):

Any one can make any sort of cable, with non standard pinout.

But, there are also variations in USBA pinout due to its evolution from 1A to 3A+ and upping of voltage.

Add to that, the cables are manufactured for different schemes.  Its possible you haven't found the right cable.

The most versatile cables have a chip in the connector  so look for those.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with [E-mark](https://www.totalphase.com/blog/2020/10/what-is-e-marker-how-does-it-work/) in the cable and your device which recognize the vendor ID of cable (part of the standard).

For example my phone activate so named Dash charging (60W) only when I use vendor cable and vendor charger.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is yes, companies can make sure only their cables work with their products. It's not super common, but there are various ways this can be done. For example, they can have the device firmware look for certain characteristics in the cable that verify it as "official".

Have you ever seen an iPhone or iPad do this?

[image]

That is a good example of how manufacturers warn or restrict customers from using unofficial cables with their products, regardless of how generic the cable connector type may appear, it's still possible.

As I said it can be done in various ways such as identification chips, voltage checks, software locks or even vendor specific signalling or encoding methods. They largely do this for legal and safety reasons, to protect themselves and their customers from unsafe usage of their electrical products. It seems very logical that a company in the baby product market would consider this a wise move.

Comment: Your example has to do with the fact the Lighting cable allows for something like this. Legal and safety reasons might be the reasons Apple says they do this but in reality they want control and it’s only partially due to trying to distance itself from the “wild wild west” environment with cheap products